# SQL Server 2005 SP3 on Windows 7 - No Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, windows-7, sql-server-2005, installation

I've been trying for a day and a half now to get SQL Server 2005, DEV edition,  to work on Windows 7, 64 bit prof.

I install from the disk, then run SP 3.  I get a failure on the Client Components section of the Installation Progress along with this vague message -

```
Product                   : Client Components
Product Version (Previous): 1399
Product Version (Final)   : 
Status                    : Failure
Log File                  : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Setup Bootstrap\LOG\Hotfix\SQLTools9_Hotfix_KB955706_sqlrun_tools.msp.log
Error Number              : 1712
Error Description         : MSP Error: 1712  One or more of the files required to restore your computer to its previous state could not be found.
```

Restoration will not be possible.

I've uninstalled all Visual Studio and tried to make this as clean as possible, and have read a lot of the blog posts, but am really at my wits end about this.  I am not a DBA, but I use SQL Server all the time when coding and testing apps.

Does anyone have any ideas as to where I can get this sorted out?  I've been ati this for a long time and have never encountered an installation as bad as this one.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you were on the correct path.  Errors like this are caused be previous pieces of software being installed that what you are now install conflict with.

In this case SQL Server 2005.  I would ensure you have no other versions, if you have say MS Visual Studio and did the default install this install a version of SQL Server.  So you might need to go into that in the Add/Remove software wizard.

If you have indeeded uninstalled all aspects of it you might have a broken install somewhere.  You would have use to use the MSI uninstall wizard however this has been depricated for MS FixIt:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/7/E/D7E37511-A7CA-4C8B-B61B-1C90895D9823/FixitCenter_Run.exe

Hopefully this will find your problem and you can then install SQL Server or just the Client tools.  This is the command line options for doing so and has saved me tons of time, replace the version number for yours I think this will works for both 2005 and 2008

```
start /wait "SQLTools2008" setup.exe /Q /ACTION=install /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /FEATURES=ADV_SSMS
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can't find the application **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio**

Locate:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\SqlWb.exe
```

Or just do a file search for:

```
SqlWb.exe
```

Run it and see if **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio** starts up

Answer (score 0):

Do you specifically need something that's not in the Express edition of SQL Server Management Studio?

If not, I'd just install Management Studio from SQL Server 2008 R2 Express. It will be able to talk to the 2005 instance just fine.

[This installer](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23650) should contain it.

Comment: It contains it, but the installer steps are a little confusing and so be aware its tricky.

Comment: True enough - maybe practice in a VM.